# Saving JSON Array List Values to variables

Tags: android, arrays, json, retrofit

I'm already able to get the JSON `ArrayList` and display the data using `RecyclerView`.

Here's how I display the JSON array using `RecyclerView` :

```
public void onResponse(Call<List<Fame>> call, Response<List<Fame>> response) {

    List<Fame> fame = response.body();

    mFameList.addAll(fame);
    adapter.notifyDatasetChanged();
    progressDialog.dismiss();
    rv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    title_text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

However, for one activity, I only need to get the values and store them to variables. I'm thinking of looping through the list but not really sure if what I'm doing is right. After storing the values to variables, I'll be able to display images based on the values. Any help is much appreciated.

Here's what I've tried so far, but it's giving me a nullpointer exception error. It works if the JSON array contains only 1 result/item.

```
    progressDialog.dismiss();
    List<Profile> p = response.body();
    if(p!=null && p.size()>0){
    pid = p.get(0).getPid();
    fname =p.get(0).getFname();
    lname = p.get(0).getLname();
}
```

Here's a sample of the JSON:

```
[
  {
    "Pid": "testID",
    "Fname": "testfname1",
    "Lname": "testlname1",
   },
  {
    "Pid": "testID",
    "Fname": "testfname2",
    "Lname": "testlname2",
   }
]
```

Comment: where you are getting null pointer? Add that code...

Comment: I think you must be getting null pointer error on `pid = p.get(0).getPid();`. So for this you need to apply one check on top of this for checking the existence of p.get(0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here's how I managed to solve the problem:

```
List<Fame> fame = response.body();
for(Fame f: fame ){
   if(f.getfName.toString() == "testfname1"){
        //do something if condition is met
    }
    //repeat step for others
}
```

I'm not sure if it's the best way to do it but it satisfies my requirements for now. :)